# Firebase get user data during onCreate

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

After an user creation, I have difficult to retrived data in a onCreate method.

```
exports.accountCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  console.log("--->"+user.data);
  console.log("ok");
  return true;
});
```

But I received an undefined value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the API documentation, the [onCreate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserBuilder#onCreate) callback method receives a [UserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserRecord) object as its first argument. Your function is calling it `user`, and is trying to access a property called `data` on it.  But you can see that UserRecord doesn't have a data property.  It has lots of other properties, so try one of them instead.  Or maybe call its [toJSON](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserRecord#toJSON) method to generate an object that you could also log.

Comment: Thanks,  but if I try to use user.uid  I receive the same error!